# How does SSL work when Tomcat runs behind IIS 6.0?

Tags: iis-6, tomcat6

I have a web service hosted on Tomcat that is behind IIS 6.0. I use Tomcat Connector to connect Tomcat to IIS.

My web service opens an SSL connection to another server:

1. Is the SSL connection made from Tomcat, or from IIS, and which SSL keystore (Windows vs. Tomcat) is used?
2. Is it possible to see the outbound SSL connection in a log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you mean in your Java code you're opening an SSL connection, then it's made from tomcat and uses tomcat's keystore.
2. Only if you log it.  I recommend logging every hit to an external dependency in an app.

Comment: The Java code is verifying credentials through LDAPS.

Comment: Tomcat doesn't seem to have its own keystore, there is no .keystore file on the server, and keytool.exe -list says Keystore files does not exist.

Comment: Interesting, are you sure it is actually making an SSL connection?  And how are you doing LDAPS; IIRC tomcat doesn't support that as part of JNDI, if you're using the LDAP Realm module that uses ssl info from the JDK itself...  Should be keystore.jks in the Java dirs somewhere.